# How to extract the transporter speed with respect to time after simulation run in an excel/DB in ANYLOGIC?

Tags: anylogic

Is there a way to extract the speed of transporters with respect to time after simulation run?

I have a model where the transporter speed varies based on path, so I want to extract that data for further analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to manage that yourself:

1. create a cyclic event
2. make it track a transporter's speed regularly
3. make it write that with the current model time into the model dbase (create a new table for that)
4. let AnyLogic copy that table to your Excel at the end

Comment: Hello,

Can you give me a simple example? I am new to this topic.

Comment: check the tutorials and how-to videos first, there are some examples doing very similar things (lacking the time to create a tailored example, sorry)

Comment: okay. But do you have the specific function that returns the spped of the transporter? I tried getMaximumSpeed(SpeedUnits units) but it returns error.

Comment: Please always open new issues for new problems. StackOverflow does not work like a forum, see https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow

Comment: Hello, 

I have a new question. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76850246/how-to-plot-the-values-extracted-by-event-in-anylogic