# How to plot the values extracted by EVENT in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

[image]

I am using an EVENT to get the speed of my transporter fleet using transporterFleet.getSpeed() every 1 second. Now, I want to get these value in a chart or Database.

I know getSpeed() returns the agent speed and not the max speed of my transporter. So, I also tried using transporterFleet.getMaximumSpeed(MPS), but it returns an error.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the actual question is. TransporterFleet has no way to get any speed, it is a fleet of transporters (a fleet cannot have speed). Do you want the speed of a transporter?

If so, you already have individual transporters as the `AGV` agent type in your model. Put the event there and use `getSpeed()` to get the speed of individual transporter agents whenever you want.

To test this, use `traceln("transporter "+getIndex()+" has speed "+getSpeed());"` in your event :)

Comment: Yes, it works. But when it shows the speed to be constant to 10 MPS for the 3600 seconds. But I set the speed of the path to 0.5 MPS. Then why is it showing 10 MPS constant for 3600 seconds.

Comment: yet a new question that would benefit from new details about the specific setup :)

Comment: Yes, I have created a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76853934/how-to-build-a-data-base-based-on-transporter-speed-index-and-time-in-anylogic